# How to display data below each other in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys please direct me how to this I want my result appear below each other please refer to my code below:

```
function displayData(e)
{
var html = '';
var html2 = '';
$searchcontainer = $('#searchcontainer');
var mapDiv = document.getElementById('mapContainer'), i = 0,
     dataIndex, tooltipDiv, key
mapMarkers = $(mapDiv).find('.e-mapMarker'), index = 0;
for (i = 0; i < mapMarkers.length; i++)
{

    if (e.target.parentNode.parentNode == mapMarkers[i])
    {
        index = i;

    }
}

html += '<div id="infocontainer">';
html += '<div class="p-image"><img src="src/images/retrofit.png"/></div>';
html += '<div class="popupdetail">';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Site Name: ' + flsSites[index].site_name + '</div>';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Site Status: ' + flsSites[index].status + '</div>';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Country: ' + flsSites[index].country_name + '</div>';
html += '</div>';
html += '</div>';
$searchcontainer = $('#searchcontainer');
if (!$(this).data('rightCont')) {
        $(this).data('rightCont', $('<div class="rightcontainer">' +
            '<img id="productimage" src="src/images/retrofit.png" onClick="DisplayProfileCard()"/>' +
            '<div id="imagedetail">' +
            '<span class="details">Product Type' + Sites[index].serial_number + '</span>' +
            '<span class="details">Version / Size <img class="row_one_icon lightbulb_icon" id="lightbulb" src="src/images/lightbulb1.png" onClick="LightBulb()" /><img id="convert" class="row_one_icon arrow_icon" src="src/images/arrow_Off.png" onClick="Conversion()"/><img id="lightning" class="row_one_icon" src="src/images/lightningOff.png" onClick="Lightning()"/><img id="bullseye" class="row_one_icon bullseye" src="src/images/bullseye_off.png" onClick="BullsEye()"/></span>' +
            '<span class="details">Estimated annual Spend <img class="row_one_icon ribbon" src="src/images/ribbon1.png"/><img class="row_one_icon map" src="src/images/map1.png"/><img class="row_one_icon paper_stack" id="paper" src="src/images/paper_stack_Off.png" onclick="PaperStack()"/><img class="row_one_icon chain" id="chain" src="src/images/chain_Off.png" onClick="ChainLink()"/></span>' +
            '<span class="details">Site name / manufacturer</span>' +
            '<span class="details">Selling Sales Eng</span>' +
            '</div></div>').appendTo($searchcontainer));
    }

    $searchcontainer.find('.rightcontainer').removeClass('background');
    $(this).data('rightCont').addClass('background');
```

now my code here works like this if I hover over a marker in the map it will display the result to my searchcontainer div but if I hover another item it will display the other result **BUT** it will overwrite the previous result instead of displaying it below

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Try to clarify what "my data", "below each other", "the other data", and "the previous" are refering to.

Comment: @Juan I have edited my question hope its clear to you now

Comment: 1) We really need more context for how this is executed in order to debug and 2) this is just really bad style- you should not be using JQuery to insert lines of code as inline strings, instead you should use Javascript Templates, or something more complex like Angular or React.

Comment: @DerekBrown hi I edit my code in the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `$(this).data` overwrites the contents of `rightCont` each time it is executed.  Read more on [the JQuery API.](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)  The `.appendTo(...)` call should be sufficient.

That being said, using string manipulation to create HTML code is stylistically terrible.  Look at something like Vue.js, Handlebars, Angular, React, or just any other frontend MVC framework- they are tools designed for easily binding Javascript data to HTML, rather than manually inserting it using string manipulation.

Comment: I would love to use MVC method but Im considering practice here in my work place for they dont like MVC :(

Comment: @Kyle how about using template literals instead? It would allow you to inject variables into your JS without all the `str1 + str2` lines:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals